# youtube API V3 probleme of (snippet, thumbs, title,) displaying videos on web page

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a problem of my api Key. when am trying a request:
I get a empty array

```
     {
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
     "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\"",
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 0
     },
    "items": [
     ]
    }
```

my key seems to be good,  before videos displayed well on website, but now i dont know why there is no response when am trying a request to get data from YouTube.

I have this method :

```
            public function getYoutube($id) 
        {
            $youtube ='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$id.'&fields=items%28snippet%28title,description,%20thumbnails%29%29&part=snippet&key=my_key';


            $json =  file_get_contents($youtube);
            $itemList = json_decode($json);

            $this->video = $itemList->items[0]; 
            $this->id = $id; 

            if(!$json)
                return false ;
            else
                return $this->video ;
        }
```

Comment: Do a debug, chaeck value of `$json`

Comment: @u_mulder thank you for your response... but when i debug, there is no data retrieved from youtube. oddly, before (sometime ago) i could see the result  (data from youtube)

Comment: Please include the id you are sending so that we can test it.

Comment: @DalmTo, this is a line with id sended :https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=K-7td3aM-So&fields=items%28snippet%28title,%20description,%20thumbnails%29%29&part=snippet&key=key

Comment: anyone can help me please ? when i test in navigator this line :https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=yIHzrn6ls_k&fields=items%28snippet%28title,%20description,%20thumbnails%29%29&part=snippet&key=my_key  everything is ok, but there is no response on distant server whereas on local server (development environment) it works also

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `file_get_contents` is failing.

1. Check your php.ini to see if [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is disabled.

In the future, always check results of functions that can return a failure, such as

```
$json =  file_get_contents($youtube);
if ( false === $json ) {
    // it failed. do something.
}
```

If it failed you can also check your server's error file it should have some more info.